# I want copy my present working directory location into a new text file

Tags: c, shell

I want to copy my present working directory location into new text file. For example, I am working in "xyz" directory and I want copy `xyz` directory path into `abc.text` file.

Is it possible in Centos or any Linux operating system?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You probably want to look up the [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) function.  It isn't clear whether you want `/home/you/xyz` written into the file (which is easy with `getcwd()`), or whether you want just the last component of the name, which is still best handled with `getcwd()` followed by the [`basename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) function.

Comment: thanks for your help.   can I replace specific line in abc.text file. for example i want paste this path in 3rd line of abc.text file

Comment: actually i am making a shell script in which specific line/specific sentence  of abc.text are replaced by PWD path. please help

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[PATH_MAX];

    if (getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf)) == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd");
        exit(1);
    }

    fp = fopen("abc.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", buf);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Shell

```
pwd > abc.txt
```